# RSA encrypt Thailand word failed by section in java

Tags: java, encryption, public-key-encryption

When I encrypt

> เชียงใหม

I can encrypt it because it is not related to encrypt by section.
but when it comes to

> เชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหมเชียงใหม

it will fail.
It shows this exception

```
org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException: input too large for RSA cipher.
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RSACoreEngine.convertInput(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RSABlindedEngine.processBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.getOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2222)
```

What I use is RSA-1024,which means when the data is more than 128 (no-padding, so 128, if not, I know it's 117), my code will do the section progress and when it separate the Thailand word, it will fail.

This is the code:

```
public class RSAUtils {


    public static final String RSA_PUBLIC_KEY = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCZDrVitNnuDj39+0FjsfAjCQsvW2gGSQUkFSBi/qn+jLC/AH3ERl8bWDmbar0n1+VocByWSOEgN4lAQ8NFgorcfcSEtUzikngsFqoMSVX3AZ3ChX3DIDCC5ImQwx8ufhlxMIKDCb3VHkh/+mEzRSUe9FYjk2wvBQHgsSQ14QA00wIDAQAB";
    public static final String RSA_PRIVATE_KEY = "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";

    private static final int MAX_ENCRYPT_BLOCK = 128;

    private static final int MAX_DECRYPT_BLOCK = 128;

    public static final String ALGORITHM = "RSA";

    private static final Provider DEFAULT_PROVIDER = new BouncyCastleProvider();

    public static PublicKey decodePublicKey(String key) throws Exception {
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(base64Check(key));
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
    }

    public static PrivateKey decodePrivateKey(String key) throws Exception {
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(base64Check(key));
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
    }


    public static String encryptBySection(String data, String keyStr, boolean isPublic) throws Exception {
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(executeBySection(decodeKey(keyStr, isPublic), Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, data.getBytes()));
    }


    public static String decryptBySection(String data, String keyStr, boolean isPublic) throws Exception {
        return new String(executeBySection(decodeKey(keyStr, isPublic), Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, Base64.decodeBase64(data)), "UTF-8");
    }

    public static String encrypt(String data, String keyStr, boolean isPublic) throws Exception{
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(execute(decodeKey(keyStr, isPublic), Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, data.getBytes()));
    }


    public static String decrypt(String data, String keyStr, boolean isPublic) throws Exception{
        return new String(execute(decodeKey(keyStr, isPublic), Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, Base64.decodeBase64(data)), "UTF-8");
    }


    private static byte[] sectionDoFinal(byte[] bytes, Cipher cipher, int blockSize) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException {

        int inputLen = bytes.length;
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int offSet = 0;
        byte[] cache;
        int i = 0;
        while (inputLen - offSet > 0) {
            if (inputLen - offSet > blockSize) {
                cache = cipher.doFinal(bytes, offSet, blockSize);
            } else {
                cache = cipher.doFinal(bytes, offSet, inputLen - offSet);
            }
            out.write(cache, 0, cache.length);
            i++;
            offSet = i * blockSize;
        }
        byte[] decryptedData = out.toByteArray();
        out.close();
        return decryptedData;
    }

    private static byte[] base64Check(String key){
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(key)){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("empty key");
        }
        byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(key.getBytes());
        if (keyBytes == null || keyBytes.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("key not encoded with base 64");
        }
        return keyBytes;
    }


    private static byte[] execute(Key key, int cipherMode, byte[] bytes) throws Exception{
        return initCipher(cipherMode, key).doFinal(bytes);
    }


    private static byte[] executeBySection(Key key, int cipherMode, byte[] bytes) throws Exception{
        if (Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE == cipherMode){
            return sectionDoFinal(bytes, initCipher(cipherMode, key), MAX_DECRYPT_BLOCK);
        }
        return sectionDoFinal(bytes, initCipher(cipherMode, key), MAX_ENCRYPT_BLOCK);
    }


    private static Cipher initCipher(int cipherMode, Key key) throws Exception{
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM, DEFAULT_PROVIDER);
        cipher.init(cipherMode, key);
        return cipher;
    }


    private static Key decodeKey(String keyStr, boolean isPublic) throws Exception{
        Key key = null;
        if (isPublic){
            key = decodePublicKey(keyStr);
        }else {
            key = decodePrivateKey(keyStr);
        }
        return key;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String data = "เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่เชียงใหม่";
        String encrypted=encryptBySection(data,RSA_PUBLIC_KEY,true);
        System.out.println(encrypted);
        long a =System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(decryptBySection(encrypted,RSA_PRIVATE_KEY,false));
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-a);
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't add information that belongs to the question in comments. Especially code in comments in hardly readable. Please edit the question and delete the comment.